# Boto3 - How to filter out attributeType from scan() output using Python Boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, boto

I'm using Boto3 to retrieve and return all data from a small dynamoDB table. My goal is to remove the attributeTypes from the output.

The following is my output:

```
    {"Items": [{"PresidentialCandidate_ID": {"S": "Trump"}, "Vote": {"N": "47"}}, {"PresidentialCandidate_ID": {"S": "Stein"}, "Vote": {"N": "16"}}, {"PresidentialCandidate_ID": {"S": "Dwayne"}, "Vote": {"N": "1"}}, {"PresidentialCandidate_ID": {"S": "none"}, "Vote": {"N": "11"}}, {"PresidentialCandidate_ID": {"S": "Johnson"}, "Vote": {"N": "13"}}, {"PresidentialCandidate_ID": {"S": "Clinton"}, "Vote": {"N": "22"}}], "Count": 6, "ScannedCount": 6}
```

My desired output:

```
    {"Items":[{"PresidentialCandidate_ID":"Trump","Vote":47},{"PresidentialCandidate_ID":"Stein","Vote":16},{"PresidentialCandidate_ID":"Dwayne","Vote":1},{"PresidentialCandidate_ID":"none","Vote":11},{"PresidentialCandidate_ID":"Johnson","Vote":13},{"PresidentialCandidate_ID":"Clinton","Vote":22}],"Count":6,"ScannedCount":6}
```

[image: DynamoDB table consist of 6 items. Primary key is PresidentialCandidate_ID]

I tried the following:

```py
    import boto3
    import json
    dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')

    def lambda_handler(event, context):

        table = dynamodb.scan(TableName="PresidentialCandidate", ConsistentRead=True)
        del table['ResponseMetadata']
        table = json.dumps(table)
        print(table)

    return {
    }
```

Any suggestion on how to filter out the attributeType to get my desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try this code only to return the data in your desired way.

```
import boto3
import json

dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    table = dynamodb.scan(TableName="PresidentialCandidate", ConsistentRead=True)
    items = table['Items']

    idx = 0
    for item in items:
        for key in item:
            value = list(item[key].values())[0]
            items[idx][key] = value
        idx += 1
    return items
```

You can also store the new desired formatted object into the table for once. This way the attributeTypes will not reflect any longer and you can have results without attributeTypes. You can try the code below to do that :)

```
import boto3
import json

dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    table = dynamodb.scan(TableName="PresidentialCandidate", ConsistentRead=True)
    items = table['Items']

    idx = 0
    for item in items:
        for key in item:
            value = list(item[key].values())[0]
            # added this line to write and replace the old format by the new formatted object
            dynamodb.put_item(TableName="PresidentialCandidate", Item=item)   
            items[idx][key] = value
        idx += 1
    return items
```

Comment: The output for your solution doesn't include the vote as Number type but rather as a String type. The desired output that I'm looking for has a number type for the vote. How can I get the vote to be a Number from your solution?

Comment: Resolved - I added a if-else statement to convert the vote to an Int in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using client, use resource, so we can avoid datatypes in the return value:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table("PresidentialCandidate")
items=  table.scan()
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.